# getLeft() not working for TextView in android

Tags: android

I created a custom control(button) in android which has a left image and center text and right arrow image. While using this custom control I have to draw upper border and lower border for this button.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
         android:id="@+id/viwupperline"
         style="@style/bsf_viwline"/> 
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytcontrollayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:layout_height="38dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgrightimage"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txttextoncontrol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgrightimage"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgarrow"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bsfarrowright" >
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>

    <View
         android:id="@+id/viwbottomline"
         style="@style/bsf_viwline"/>
```

If i am using only one button, then full upper border and lower border have to show. Otherwise bottom border should be drawn in alignment with TextView. I created view for the borders. I took getLeft() for the TextView. and if bottom border should be minimized i set marginleft for the view as following:

```
public void AddMarginToLowerBorder()
{
    int margin = _text.getLeft();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)_viewlower.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(margin, 0, 0, 0);
    _viewlower.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

But getLeft() is not working.

If i set like this,

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)_viewlower.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(70, 0, 0, 0);
    _viewlower.setLayoutParams(params);
```

,then it is working properly.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use getLeft() (and getTop and so on) before your view has not shown. Instead of manually calculating margins, place your borders into RelativeLayout and use `android:layout_below`/`android:layout_above`/`android:layout_toRightOf.` properties.